# plotting regression line in with lattice

Tags: r, lattice

I'm having a bit of a trouble here, please help me.
I have this data

```
set.seed(4)
mydata <- data.frame(var = rnorm(100),
                     temp = rnorm(100),
                     subj = as.factor(rep(c(1:10),5)),
                     trt = rep(c("A","B"), 50))
```

and this model that fits them

```
lm  <- lm(var ~ temp * subj, data = mydata)
```

I want to plot the results with **lattice** and fit the regression line, predicted with my model, through them. To do so, I'm using this approach, outlined  "Lattice Tricks for the power useR" by D. Sarkar

```
temp_rng <- range(mydata$temp, finite = TRUE)

grid <- expand.grid(temp = do.breaks(temp_rng, 30),
                    subj = unique(mydata$subj),
                    trt = unique(mydata$trt))

model <- cbind(grid, var = predict(lm, newdata = grid))

orig <- mydata[c("var","temp","subj","trt")]

combined <- make.groups(original = orig, model = model)


xyplot(var ~ temp | subj, 
       data = combined,
       groups = which,
       type = c("p", "l"),
       distribute.type = TRUE
       )
```

So far every thing is fine, but I also want to assign a fill color to the data points for the two treatments `trt=1` and `trt=2`.

So I have written this piece of code, that works fine, but when it comes to plot the regression line, it seems that type is not recognized by the panel function...

```
my.fill <- c("black", "grey")

plot <- with(combined,
        xyplot(var ~ temp | subj,
              data = combined,
              group = combined$which,
              type = c("p", "l"),
              distribute.type = TRUE,
              panel = function(x, y, ..., subscripts){
                     fill <- my.fill[combined$trt[subscripts]] 
                     panel.xyplot(x, y, pch = 21, fill = my.fill, col = "black")
                     },
             key = list(space = "right",
                     text = list(c("trt1", "trt2"), cex = 0.8),
                     points = list(pch = c(21), fill = c("black", "grey")),
                     rep = FALSE)
                     )
      )
plot
```

I've also tried to move type and distribute type within `panel.xyplot`, as well as subsetting the data in it `panel.xyplot` like this

```
plot <- with(combined,
        xyplot(var ~ temp | subj,
              data = combined,
              panel = function(x, y, ..., subscripts){
                     fill <- my.fill[combined$trt[subscripts]] 
                     panel.xyplot(x[combined$which=="original"], y[combined$which=="original"], pch = 21, fill = my.fill, col = "black")
                     panel.xyplot(x[combined$which=="model"], y[combined$which=="model"], type = "l", col = "black")
                     },
             key = list(space = "right",
                     text = list(c("trt1", "trt2"), cex = 0.8),
                     points = list(pch = c(21), fill = c("black", "grey")),
                     rep = FALSE)
                     )
      )
plot
```

but no success with that either.

Can anyone help me to get the predicted values plotted as a line instead of being points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a job for the `latticeExtra` package.

```
library(latticeExtra)
p1 <- xyplot(var ~ temp | subj, data=orig, panel=function(..., subscripts) {
  fill <- my.fill[combined$trt[subscripts]] 
  panel.xyplot(..., pch=21, fill=my.fill, col="black")
})
p2 <- xyplot(var ~ temp | subj, data=model, type="l")
p1+p2
```

[image]

I'm not sure what's going on in your first attempt, but the one with the subscripts isn't working because x and y are a subset of the data for subj, so subsetting them using a vector based on `combined` won't work the way you think it will.  Try this instead.

```
xyplot(var ~ temp | subj, groups=which, data = combined,
       panel = function(x, y, groups, subscripts){
         fill <- my.fill[combined$trt[subscripts]]
         g <- groups[subscripts]
         panel.points(x[g=="original"], y[g=="original"], pch = 21, 
                      fill = my.fill, col = "black")
         panel.lines(x[g=="model"], y[g=="model"], col = "black")
       },
       key = list(space = "right",
         text = list(c("trt1", "trt2"), cex = 0.8),
         points = list(pch = c(21), fill = c("black", "grey")),
         rep = FALSE)
       )
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be trivial, but you may try:

```
xyplot(... , type=c("p","l","r"))
```

"`p`" adds points, "`l`" connects them with broken lines, "`r`" fits a linear model through your data. `type="r"` alone will plot only regression lines without showing data points.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to simply use the `panel.lmline` function on just your original data:

```
xyplot(var ~ temp | subj,
        data = orig,
        panel = function(x,y,...,subscripts){
            fill <- my.fill[orig$trt[subscripts]]
            panel.xyplot(x, y, pch = 21, fill = my.fill,col = "black")
            panel.lmline(x,y,col = "salmon")
        },
        key = list(space = "right",
                     text = list(c("trt1", "trt2"), cex = 0.8),
                     points = list(pch = c(21), fill = c("black", "grey")),
                     rep = FALSE)
)
```

[image]

Comment: indeed that is simpler, but i couldn'd use that approach because that doese not actually fit the model...

Comment: @matteo I'm not sure what you mean. Using the example data you provide, the fitted lines you get using `panel.lmline` are the same as those you'd get using the output from `lm`. If you need the model information elsewhere, there's nothing stopping you from fitting it anyway; my point is that you don't need it for the plot itself.

Comment: Indeed, joran, that would be simpler, but I can’t use that approach because that does not actually give the regression line of the model...those regression lines are just "fit by eye" trough the data in each panel. In my real case for example, the lines have different slopes whereas there is no significant effect of subj on the slope, but only on the intercept... hope it make sense

Comment: While other models may differ, @joran is correct for this particular case where the model has a `temp*subject` interaction; `panel.lmline` fits a linear model using `lm` on the data in each panel, which will have exactly the same fitted values as your model.

Comment: Absolutely @Aaron, I recon my example was misleading, apologise for that.